# slideDown('slow').delay(1500).slideUp('slow') how to slideUp() before its function finishes?

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
if(error == false)
   $('#messageError').slideDown('slow').delay(1500).slideUp('slow');
else
   $('#messageError').slideUp('slow');
```

if `error` equals `false` then `$('#messageError')`pops up, and in 1.5 seconds it goes off. Imagine before delay time is up, the `error` equals `true`. I want to hide it before it hides itself.

The only thing works is `hide()`, but I want to 'hide' it same way it popped up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/)

`stop()` forces to stop the current animation.

For example:

```
if(error == false)
    $('#messageError').slideDown('slow').delay(1500).slideUp('slow');
else
    $('#messageError').stop().slideUp('slow');
```

**Reminder about chaining vs callback**

Chaining like you did only works for animation queue, if you want to do other processing code e.g. `css()`(which isn't queued) use the callback method.

For example:

```
// The `css();` is immediately fired before sliding down, not after!
$('#messageError').slideDown('slow').css({'opacity:0.5'}).delay(1500).slideUp('slow');

// Here it changes opacity after the slide down
$('#messageError').slideDown('slow', function(){
    $(this).css({'opacity:0.5'}).delay(1500).slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: awesome!!! I should have thought myself about stopping the animation first, cuz it's in process. LOGIC!!!

Comment: No problem, I hope this answered your question, and you mark it if so. Here is some more information on the animation processing queue: https://learn.jquery.com/effects/queue-and-dequeue-explained/

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use the `slideToggle` jQuery function so you don't have to work out if it is in state up or down. You also need to use the `stop` function so it will interrupt the animation.

Here is the jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/drjk7mvv/

jQuery

```
$(function () {
    $('.slideToggle').on('click', function () {
        $('#messageError').stop().slideToggle('slow');
    });

});
```

Html

```
<button type="button" class="slideToggle">Toggle error</button>
<div id="messageError">
     <h1>ERROR</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#messageError
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #F00;
}
```

Comment: why not simply
`$('#messageError').stop().slideUp('slow');` ?

Comment: Well you can do just slideUp, but the reason i used `slideToggle` was just to show you how the `stop` function works.

Comment: yeahh, I just clicked to your jsFiddle link, Toggle is awesome, it's Up and Down at the same time! like ToggleClass instead of AddClass and RemoveClass!

Comment: @AlexMcManns I hope it helped, remember to tick an answer if it is correct